# How to create a lead record of the same lead record which was converted

Tags: lead-conversion

The lead record must be created with the same fields with Converted checkbox checked and with read only fields.

Comment: Could you add information to your question that explains in which situation you need this Lead copy and what purpose the new record has?! This will facilitate answering.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you convert a Lead, the box becomes checked and the record is read-only. An additional permission, Edit Converted Leads, is needed to modify these records. In other words, based on your question, you don't need to do anything.